# How can I append riot tag to the root through JS?

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I have the following code:

```
<my-tag>

    <script>
        var self = this;
        riot.route('/test', function() {
            self.root.innerHTML = '<some-riot-tag></some-riot-tag>';
            self.update();
        });
    </script>
</my-tag>
```

If I add it without JS, it works:

```
<my-tag>
    <some-riot-tag></some-riot-tag>
</my-tag>
```

How can I make this work using javascript? The tag is added to the DOM; however, it is not updated.

EDIT: small changes.

Comment: Is this because you want to have 'dynamic' tags in `my-tag`? So that on route x, tag x is rendered, and route y => tag y?

Comment: Yes. I don't know if this is the proper way to do it but I have no idea how else I can achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem with your solution is that Riot doesn't parse the inserted HTML via JavaScript as a Riot tag. A different approach could work better, for instance:

```
<my-tag>
    <some-riot-tag if="{ route == 'test' }" />
    <other-riot-tag if="{ route == 'bar' }" />

    <script>
        var self = this;
        riot.route('/test', function() {
            self.route = 'foo';
            self.update();
        });
        riot.route('/bar', function() {
            self.route = 'bar';
            self.update();
        });
    </script>
</my-tag>
```

Another approach could be using the `riot-tag` attribute (I haven't tested this, but it should work):

```
<my-tag>

    <div riot-tag="{ tagName }"></div>

    <script>
        var self = this;
        riot.route('/test', function() {
            self.tagName = 'some-riot-tag';
            self.update();
        });
        riot.route('/bar', function() {
            self.tagName = 'other-riot-tag';
            self.update();
        });
    </script>
</my-tag>
```

**Edit**: seems like `riot-tag` will be deprecated in the (near) future, but the solution could still work using `data-is`: http://riotjs.com/guide/#html-elements-as-tags (sadly, proper documentation on this seems to be sparse).

Comment: Thank you! The first approach worked. The second one didn't work. I tried both `riot-tag` and `data-is` but no luck. I am happy though.

Comment: Good to hear! Probably, the second approach suffers from the same problem as your initial script: after setting `riot-tag="some-riot-tag"` it doesn't parse the div[riot-tag] as an actual Riot tag